# Sending Money to a Bitcoin Address

Tags: money-transfer

I would like to know how to send money from one’s debit card to a person’s Bitcoin address. Is it possible to do this without having to create one’s own Bitcoin wallet?

Comment: It sounds like you want to buy bitcoin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I send Bitcoins without a wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43999/can-i-send-bitcoins-without-a-wallet)

Comment: Thank you. I will read that discussion. It may contain the answer. I want to explain to a person how to send money to my Bitcoin address. The person does not have a Bitcoin wallet. Therefore, I need to know how he can send the money from his bank account.

Comment: Thank you for the information. If I understand correctly, to send money from a debit card to a Bitcoin address, it is necessary to visit a service like Coinbase, create an account in this service, and enter one’s debit card information and the Bitcoin address to which the money will be sent. Is this correct, or is something else needed?
Are fees for transfers usually small?